# Rearrange a probability measure without changing its marginals

Tags: probability-theory

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

Anyway, it is written as problem. Have fun! :)

---

Let $\mu, \nu$ be probability measures (p.m.'s) on $X, Y$ respectively. Let $\pi$ be a p.m. on $X \times Y$ with marginals $\mu, \nu$ respectively. Let $(A_i)_{i=1}^n$ be a finite sequence of measurable subsets of $X \times Y$ such that $\pi(A_i) > 0$ for all $i$. We define p.m. $\pi_i$ on $X \times Y$ by
$$
\pi_i(B) := \frac{\pi(B\cap A_i)}{\pi(A_i)}.
$$

Let $P^X, P^Y$ be the projections from $X\times Y$ to $X,Y$ respectively. Let
$$
\mu_i := P^X_\sharp \pi_i \quad \text{and} \quad \nu_i := P^Y_\sharp \pi_i.
$$

> Let $0<\alpha < \frac{1}{n} \min_i \pi(A_i)$ and $\sigma$ be a permutation of $(1,\ldots, n)$. Let
> $$
> \lambda := \pi - \alpha\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i \otimes \nu_{\sigma(i)}.
> $$
> Then $\lambda$ is a p.m. on $X \times Y$ with marginals $\mu, \nu$ respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the sum of measures is a (signed) measure. Second,
$$
\alpha \pi_i(B) = \alpha \frac{\pi(B\cap A_i)}{\pi(A_i)} \le \frac{\pi(B\cap A_i)}{n} \le \frac{\pi(B)}{n}.
$$

So $\lambda$ is non-negative. Next,
$$
\lambda(X \times Y) = 1 - \alpha\sum_{i=1}^n 1 + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n 1 = 1.
$$

It follows that $\lambda$ is a p.m. Finally,
$$
\begin{align}
P^X_\sharp \lambda &= P^X_\sharp \left (\pi - \alpha\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i \otimes \nu_{\sigma(i)} \right) \\
&=  P^X_\sharp \pi - \alpha\sum_{i=1}^n P^X_\sharp \pi_i + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n P^X_\sharp( \mu_i \otimes \nu_{\sigma(i)}) \\
&= \mu -\alpha \sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i\\
&= \mu.
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
P^Y_\sharp \lambda &= P^Y_\sharp \left (\pi - \alpha\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i \otimes \nu_{\sigma(i)} \right) \\
&=  P^Y_\sharp \pi - \alpha\sum_{i=1}^n P^Y_\sharp \pi_i + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n P^Y_\sharp( \mu_i \otimes \nu_{\sigma(i)}) \\
&= \nu -\alpha \sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n\nu_{\sigma(i)}\\
&= \nu.
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.